# Adding a new button to WinEdt 9.1

Tags: winedt

I am trying to add a new button to the WinEdt 9.1 toolbar menu.  I have already put in place the command in the MainMenu.ini file:

```
ITEM="Matlab"
CAPTION="Matlab"
IMAGE="Matlab"
MACRO="Run('"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin\matlab.exe" "%N%T""','%P','',100,0,'','','',111);"`
```

and also updated the Toolbar.ini file.  However, in the the toolbar, the place where the icon should show up, shows up blank.  The new icon is a 16x16 .png file in the "...\WinEdt Team\WinEdt9\Bitmaps\Images" folder.  If I hover my mouse around the place where the icon should show up on the toolbar, I do see the caption ("Matlab") and a raised blank box.  I know in the past WinEdt version (version 5) that you had to modify a WinEdt.btn file and add a line with your new icon, but I do not see that file anymore.  Is there somewhere else you have to specify your newly added icon?

Comment: Read the comments in images.ini.

Comment: Did you install the bitmaps in your private settings directory (`%b`)?

Comment: @Bernard, I put the bitmap into the C:\Program Files\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 9\Bitmaps\Images folder.  I also went into the Images.ini file and modifed "USE_LOCAL_FOLDER=1" in the IMAGE_WIDTH=16 and IMAGE_HEIGHT=16 section but I still cannot see the icon.

Comment: From my experience with WinEdt 8, it should be in `C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 9\Bitmaps`, and modifications to MainManu.ini should be in `C:\Users\Bernard\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 9\ConfigEx`.

Comment: @Bernard, I do not see the Bitmaps folder in the path that you suggested.  There are only the folders: Config, ConfigEx, Dict and Exex and then some other files.

Comment: Of course! you have to create it. All personal additions must go there (in %b) if you don't want the .ini files  to be overwritten on updates.

Comment: @Bernard, I got something to show up now after following your suggestions.  I created the folder   C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 9\Bitmaps\Images and put the png files in there.  However, I now see a black box.   I made the png file 16x16.  Is the image not formatted correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24934/discussion-between-bernard-and-joe).

Comment: @Joe: I solved your problem: the icons must have `alpha transparency`. I found a .png image with transparency, format 128×128, and resized it to 16×16, and it works. Where can I make it available?

Comment: @Bernard, thanks for looking into this.  What program did you use to resize with the alpha transparency?

Comment: `xnview` worked fine, and apparently  it kept α transparency while resizing. Seems not to be guaranteed for all software… B. t. w., would you be interested by an `installer/uninstaller` for your modifications to WinEdt?

Comment: are you referring to an install/uninstaller my winedt program?

Comment: For what it's worth, in WinEdt 10.2 there is a `Matlab` icon in the default ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advice
 **Read the comments in images.ini.** – Ulrike Fischer Jun 17 '15 at 21:31 
given by Fischer is perfectly correct, but perhaps too brief for anyone searching for a solution to winedt icon problems.

In WinEdt 9 and 10 (10.1 is the Sept 2016 official version) there is a file called **Images.ini** in the program folder. I found it in subdirectory ConfigEx.

Read the text therein (as Fischer suggested).

It says to use local images, you must edit Images.ini and change the settings. The simplest edit is to change the digit (either 0 or 1) after USE_RESOURCE_DLL and USE_SOURCE_FOLDER.

A simple example is to replace the 16x16 AcroRead and AcroFind images with similar 16x16 images for Sumatra PDF. The AcroRead.png image was found in subdirectory **Bitmaps/Images**. A search for this file name will unearth its location in any WinEdt install. A safe experiment is to rename AcroRead.png to AcroRead.png.orig and then copy a new 16x16 image to this directory with file name AcroRead.png.

Please note that installs of winedt 5,6,7,8 did not have a resource DLL for images. The DLL is used by default in winedt 9, 10. The BitMaps/Images directory is still there, but not used unless enabled (see above).

Comment: Enabled means enabled in WinEdt. Use menu "Options"  ==>  "Options Interface" followed by editing Images.ini in WinEdt. This action creates a new file Images.ini (same name) in the User directory in Windows. There is a button far left in row 2 of the Options Interface that saves the file there and enables the new content. There are 28 edits needed in Images.ini to change USE_RESOURCE_DLL and USE_SOURCE_FOLDER. Do not use a programming editor in the Program Files directory - those files must remain originals!  Images added to folder Bitmaps/Images are expected to be 16x16 transparent.